# Can not access backend connection from client to server

Tags: java, tomcat

We have one project, the front end is written in angular and the back end in java. Both projects run on a tomcat server. When I run the application on the server it works just fine but when I try to access the server from a client, I can not access the back end. Does Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Verify that you have written right IP address of the server system while building the frontend application

Answer (score 1):

The back end should be serving your angular front end. Then they come from the same host and they are allowed to interact.

Often people forget to run `ng build` on their angular projects. `ng build` creates a new folder of files that the browser can read, and you have to serve those files as static from a web server.

https://angular.io/guide/deployment

`ng run` (localhost:4200) is only meant to help you develop the front end without worrying about the back end, but when you're done you have to worry about the back end.